# Getting two XML validation events for one error

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax, xml-validation

I am trying to validate an XML file that has an error but this error is being reported in two different formats.  I just want one event and I have a preference of which format.

Here is what I am seeing:

```
[severity=FATAL_ERROR,message=cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'G' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[M, F]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.,locator=[node=null,object=null,url=null,line=-1,col=-1,offset=-1]]
[severity=FATAL_ERROR,message=cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'G' of element 'Gender' is not valid.,locator=[node=null,object=null,url=null,line=-1,col=-1,offset=-1]]
```

I prefer the second format as it reports the element.

Currently I am using a `ValidationEventHandler` that simply prints the event out like so:

```
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

public class MessageValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler 
{
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent ve) 
    {
        System.out.println(ve);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The XSD file (simplified) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Message">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Gender" type="STGenderCode" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:simpleType name="STGenderCode">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="M"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="F"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

With this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NexusMessage.xsd">
      <Gender>G</Gender>
</Message>
```

What do I have to do to either know that these two events are related so I can intentional ignore one - OR - better yet have only one of the two events.

I am trying to generate a report for the clients to view and or correct errors and I don't want to report the same error twice.

If there is another way to do this I would be open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting from a schema processor is never going to be ideal, and you have very little opportunity to improve it, except perhaps by filtering and minor reformatting. You could try a different schema processor to see if its messages are more to your taste, but there will always be aberrations like this. This processor is perhaps taking a little bit literally the requirement to report which clauses in the specification are being breached; there is often more than one. Alternatively, what often happens is that within the validator, different information is available at different levels of the software and it's often easiest to tell you at one level that (say) a date was found to be invalid, and at a higher level where that date appeared in your source.

Comment: Thanks for answering - can you suggest another processor or technique?

Comment: The obvious alternative XSD processor in the Java world is my own Saxon product. But you will almost certainly find that some aspects of its error reporting are better and others are worse (well, it's partly a matter of taste anyway.)

Comment: Thanks - lets see if our error reporting tastes are compatible then :)